# Smoothing the curve in the line graph python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am plotting my data by using primary and secondary axis. My secondary axis have a line graph. I want to know how to smooth the curve of the lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

flatui1 = ["#0C6514", "#18AB25"]
# flatui1 = ["#0B1853","#089590"]
flatui2 = ["#0E1D56", "#18AB25"]
colors = sns.color_palette(flatui1)
cmap1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", colors)
colors = sns.color_palette(flatui2)
cmap2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", colors)
sns.set_style(style='white') # we don't want the grid coming from seaborn

m1_t = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[0.055,0.044,0.289,0.052,0.198,0.184,0.183,0.135,0.101,0.209],
    "B":[0.027,0.012,0.238,0.029,0.198,0.171,0.133,0.114,0.039,0.165],
    "C":[50.90,72.72,17.64,44.23,0.0,7.065,27.32,15.55,61.38,21.05]
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
twin_x = ax.twinx() # Create a pseudo axes based off of the original


# Put the bar plot on the "primary y" via ax=ax
m1_t[['A','B']].plot(kind='bar',colormap=cmap1, ax=ax, zorder=1,legend=False,figsize=(10,5))

# Put the line plot on the "secondary y" via ax=twin_x

m1_t['C'].plot(kind='line', color='darkorange', linewidth=3, ax=twin_x,marker='o' ,zorder=2,legend=False)
ax.grid(True, zorder=0)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.set_xticklabels(('P0', 'P1','P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9'))

# X and Y axis label
ax.set_xlabel('Id')
ax.set_ylabel('Loss')


 
# To create 1 all encompassing legend:

plt.show()
```

The below graph image is for your reference,

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. [Works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz3BM.png).

Comment: With using the same code?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Which IDE you use to run this code? I tried VS Code and Jupyter still same.

Comment: Works for me in both Jupyter and Spyder. Try restarting your kernel.

Comment: Its not working even after restarting kernel and pc

Comment: Same here, it works perfectly (Matplotlib 3.2, MacOS 11 beta, Python 3.8). What are your Python and Matplotlib versions? On which OS are you working?

Comment: Maybe very old versions of pandas or seaborn? But anyhow, `ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 9.5)` should work.

Comment: May be, Thanks it works in another PC. However, do you know how to smoorth the line of the line graph.